# IIS_IUSRS Can Access a File, but Application Pool Identity User Cannot

Tags: windows, permissions, iis-7.5, file-permissions, application-pools

I am trying to understand IIS file permissions.  A given file has "full control" permissions for IIS_IUSRS.  But it seems all Application Pool Identity users cannot access the file.  (I have noticed that some of my Application Pool Identity users were not members of IIS_IUSRS for some reason, so I simply added them manually.)

When a given Application Pool Identity is a member of IIS_IUSRS, how can it be that the Application Pool Identity user cannot access the file if IIS_IUSRS can access it?  Please see my screenshots below.  Thank you.

[IIS_IUSRS has "Full Control."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wp0Te.png)

[IIS_IUSRS also has "Full Control" under "Effective Permissions," but a given Application Pool Identity user has no permissions under "Effective Permissions."](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Snrjl.png)

Answer (score 7):

When using anonymous authentication by default IIS uses a specific user named `IUSR` to access files. This user is automatically a member of the Windows `Users` but not a member of `IIS_IUSRS`

If you removed permissions for `Users` from your files, the default site setup wont work anymore.

I usually don't use `IUSR`, to change this in the GUI, select the server or site node and open the `Authentication` icon, select `Anonymous Authentication` and the `Edit` in the Actions pane on the right:

[image: Anonymous Authentication settings in IIS]

change from a specific user to `Application pool identity`, now the file access is done via this account and it should be able to access your files.

You can do the same in PowerShell:

For the whole server:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -filter "system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication" -name "userName" -value ""
```

For a specific site:

```
Set-WebConfigurationProperty -pspath 'MACHINE/WEBROOT/APPHOST' -location 'SiteName' -filter "system.webServer/security/authentication/anonymousAuthentication" -name "userName" -value ""
```

I wrote a bit about this in a [blog post](http://peter.hahndorf.eu/blog/iisntfsacls.html)

Comment: Thank you, but I'm interested in fixing the permissions issue first please.  Why can IIS_IUSRS access the file, but the Application Pool Identity user can't?  Please see my second screenshot.

Comment: @user1325179 - I would just say the `effective access` tool doesn't always work for special accounts like `IIS APPPOOL\*`, because additional security tokens are inserted into the process at runtime. Just see whether you still have a problem after changing the anonymousAuthentication identity.

Comment: @PeterHandorf, no, that didn't work.  ASP.NET still reports that access is denied.  Thank you though.

Comment: @user1325179 - Assuming you have a 401.3, I would use `Failed Request Tracing` to look closer into it. Look for events: `MODULE_SET_RESPONSE_ERROR_STATUS`, and ` FILE_CACHE_ACCESS_START`.

Comment: @PeterHandorf, I'm not getting a 401.3 error.  Again, thank you anyway.